# Udacity CS253 using GAE, Handler Errors

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, httphandler

I have run into a roadblock. It so happens another student, Ahmad, has run into a largely similar roadblock at the same time. So far, we don't have an answer from the Udacity forums, so I thought I would cross post here in hopes of getting help sooner rather than later. The problems comes up here: [Web Development - Lesson 2 - More Handlers](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs253/l-48736183/e-48754023/m-48735107). (The link might not work if you aren't logged-in).

Up until this point, both of us were getting it right and making progress, but from here on, things shut down and we are both stumped. Here is my last post back to Ahmad:

I compared your log with mine in MS Word. When you get rid of things like time of day, font, and file path, there are a couple of differences. We both got:

> WARNING   api_server.py:331] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.

And

> ERROR     wsgi.py:262]

Our tracebacks are nearly identical

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files\ (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
>       handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
>     File "C:\Program Files\ (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
>       handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
>     File "C:\Program Files\ (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
>       obj = **import**(path[0])

but we have different form actions
`(/<form action ="/testform, TestHandler)],">`

One thing I have that you don’t is

> WARNING  2013-12-09 18:18:41,795 simple_search_stub.py:1018] Could not read search indexes from c:\users\appdata\local\temp\appengine.udacity7676\search_indexes

So where do we go from here? I don’t know, but I do have a lot of questions I hope someone can and will answer:

1. If this PIL module is so crucial, why is it a separate download? And why didn’t GAE tell us that before now?
2. Why did we both succeed with the Udacity quizzes until this point? Put another way, what is so different about this exercise that suddenly makes PIL crucial?
3. I looked at PIL on the app engine site. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/ It is an image manipulator, and the example they give is with the gae icon. That makes me wonder if our progress on this lesson has been shipwrecked by someone requiring the icon be part of the result? As near as I can tell, there are no images in this exercise, and I don’t know of ANY app where the lack of a favicon makes the whole thing crash. If that’s what’s going on, that’s just crazy and wasteful.
4. I went to the PIL download site. Turns out the installer not only expects to find Python at the default location [c:\python27], there is NO WAY to give it another path. I tried – many times. Since my python is not at the default location, either I am out of luck or I have to reinstall it there, and start all over again. How nice and thoughtful of these engineers to be so flexible in working with newbies like us.
5. I am mindful of the fact that you said you had in fact already installed PIL, but you got this error message anyway. So what do we do with that?
6. I also compared the code in the lesson with the code I have for this exercise.
7. I have `MainHandler`, they have `MainPage`, which I had noticed
   before, but I don’t think this is significant. Besides, mine came
   with this name, I didn’t create it.
8. The triple quotes seem to be spaced differently, but I’m pretty sure I heard elsewhere that spacing doesn’t matter, so that shouldn’t be a problem.
9. I don’t have the content-type line, the instructor commented his out.
10. He adds `out`, as in `self.response.out.write(form)`. This was not in my default files. I just have `self.response.write(form)`.

Comment: Ashish Nitin Patil's answer covers the rest of the points, but, for completeness, self.response.out is an alias for self.response (it just returns itself) for compatibility with a previous version of the framework, so either version is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `(/<form action ="/testform, TestHandler)],">` does not look right.
It should be `<form action="/testform">` only.

The `PIL` library is not at all necessary for the GAE (in your case at the least). So, it's just a *warning* which you can ignore. (It has nothing to do with your errors)

The `MainHandler` replaced with `MainPage` is not at all a problem if you have used the correct Handler `class` in the `app` declaration at the end. Something like,

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/testform', TestHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Also, the spacing doesn't matter, but the *block* in which you place the *triple-quoted strings* matters. e.g.

```
form = 
"""
<form action="/testform">
    <input name="q"> <input type="submit">
</form>
"""
```

would give error, but,

```
form =       """
<form action="/testform">
    <input name="q"> <input type="submit">
</form>
"""
```

this would work fine.

As for the actual problem you two are facing, I can't help you if I can't have a look at the code. If you want the discussion to continue on the Udacity forums, it's fine by me, but then, post a link & I will see what I can do.

**Update** - Looks like you missed adding commas to separate the tuples in your URL-Handlers declaration. Your code looks like

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)
                               ('/testform', TestHandler)]
                              debug=True)
```

while it should be

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), # <-- comma at the end of line
                               ('/testform', TestHandler)], # <-- comma before hash
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish. We can stay here. The only new post on the Udacity thread is Ahmad saying he was manipulating his code and now it works, but he has no idea what he did so he can't help me..._sigh_

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> INFO     2013-12-15 21:18:40,151 module.py:617] default: "GET / 
>
> HTTP/1.1" 500 -
> INFO     2013-12-15 21:18:40,190 module.py:617] default: "GET 
>
> /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
> ERROR    2013-12-16 03:18:48,500 wsgi.py:262] 
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "C:\...\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
>
>     handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
>
>   File "C:\...\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
>
>     handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
>
>   File "C:\...\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
>
>     obj = __import__(path[0])
>
>   File "C:\...\udacity7676\main.py", line 18, in <module>
>
>     ('/testform', TestHandler)],
>
> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
>
> INFO     2013-12-15 21:18:48,512 module.py:617] default: "GET / 
>
> HTTP/1.1" 500 -
> ```

I'm guessing the handler names don't line up and that's the problem, but I'd rather get your feedback before plunging ahead blindly. I would also guess the tuple is not callable for the same reasons. But I don't recall any instructions to modify `wsgi.py`. I would also guess that the favicon error goes to this *PIL* issue.

Comment: Please note the line `app = webapp2...` You need to pass a `list` of tuples to it! Verify your `app` variable is something like the one in my answer above, like  `([(), (), ()], debug=True)`

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil I'm sorry. I don't understand. First, if you look at the image file I posted and linked to above, you will see that my app = webapp2 line is exactly the same as the instructors. If you mean that each part should be in its own parenthesis. I tried that and still got a syntax error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\...\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\...\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler

    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\...\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject

    obj = __import__(path[0])

  File "C:\Users\...\udacity7676\main.py", line 18

    (/testform), (TestHandler)],
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Then I tried it with both the single quotes and the parenthesis:    ('/testform'), (TestHandler)],

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I don't think I put your name in right the last time. Hopefully you will get this message and respond. I have no idea why none of this works.

Comment: Yep, I got all the notifications (since it is *my* answer/post). Looks like you missed commas `,` to separate the tuples in the list! Please correct that in your `app = webapp2...` line. Hence the errors. Updating my answer to reflect the same,  comments are not good for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it. There is a comma between testform and testhandler, and one after testhandler. what am I missing?!  I do see that there is no comma after MainHandler, so I put that in and tried just now. I still get a blank page, but a different error:   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1142, in add

    for r in route.get_match_routes():

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_match_routes'      
There was more but I'm out of space and I think this is the essence of it. Thanks.

Comment: Hang in there, I'll give you the image showing the required comma.

Comment: Here you go - http://imgur.com/exLZUy0 Note the red circled areas. That's the missing comma.

Comment: Did you mean now? I'm going to lay down for an hour, I've been at this most of the night, and check back then. thx.

Comment: Yes! I just saw that, that's why I got the new error message I just mentioned... 8 minutes ago, according to Stack Overflow. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373309/why-this-code-gets-this-str-object-has-no-attribute-get-match-routes-error

Comment: You should just put up the code from my answer. I think it's quite the same thing that you want. So that the typos & other silly errors are avoided.